# Get Mailbox name in Outlook Addin using VSTO

Tags: outlook, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-object-model

I'm working on Outlook 2003 AddIn using VSTO.Is there a way to Get the *Mailbox Name* OR *NTUserName* of the user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To Get the user name logged on via outlook use [Application.NameSpace.CurrentUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb220041.aspx)

To get the Mailbox Name in 2007 use [Store.DisplayName Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb207416.aspx)

(Edit)
In Outlook 2003 you can get the parent of the Inbox folder and the name property should be what you want.

```
Set myNameSpace = myOlApp.GetNameSpace("MAPI")
Set myFolder= myNameSpace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set myParentFolder = myFolder.Parent
```

Marcus

Comment: *Store* is available only in Outlook 2007.. Is there a way to achieve the same in Outlook 2003

Comment: Oops sorry forgot that you are using 2003, In 2003 Current user is there, the OOM does not expose it. You can get it playing with the parent of the Inbox. as above

Comment: The above approach does not work if default mail delivery location is Personal Folder(.pst data file)..

Comment: Are yes , I think you will have to go to MAPI using redemption then As I say the 2003 OOM does not expose it.